# How to autostart wget to download files when internet connection gets up?

Tags: wget

I am using Windows XP.

i have created a batch file containing `wget -i links.txt --read-timeout=2 -t 0 -w 0 --waitretry=0 -c --no-check-certificate -b` and the file "links.txt" contains URLs pointing to files I wish to download.

I've placed this batch file and "links.txt" in "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" directory, in order to make wget start when my computer boots.

However, it takes some time to for my internet connection to get up when I start my computer. Thus the the batch file runs before my connection is up, so wget fails to download anything.

So, is there anyway to run in the background a batch file or wget when internet connection is established?

Comment: Is the time your internet connection needs to work its way into connected state somewhat constant? If that is the case, could you just introduce an appropriate sleep in the beginning of your batch file?

Answer (score 0):

Build a small loop that checks for an up connection by pinging a host. E. g.

```
:loop
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 1 -w 60000 | find "TTL=" || goto :loop

wget -i links.txt --read-timeout=2 -t 0 -w 0 --waitretry=0 -c --no-check-certificate -b
```